# Siunitx Won't Display Reciprocal Powers

Tags: siunitx, units

I have several SI units in my document which I would like to typeset using the `siunitx` package. According to the documentation the default mode for the `\per` command is 'reciprocal' meaning `\si{m\per s}` should produce output akin to `ms$^{-1}$` but on my system it is producing `m/s`.

I have tried setting `\sisetup{per=reciprocal}` and `\sisetup{per-mode=reciprocal}` but it seems to ignore this and continues to use '/'.

Specifying the mode for individual units works but I don't want to have to type `[per-mode=reciprocal]` every time I want to typeset a unit.

Am I missing something or is there a way to fix this (preferably without `\newcommand`)?

Comment: Could you add a minimal example?

Comment: You only get reciprocals in 'interpreted' mode: did you try `\si{\m\per\s}` or similar?

Comment: @JosephWright It seems this is the issue. It wasn't clear to me despite referring to the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 'unit parser' in `siunitx` only operates on 'symbolic' units such as

```
\si{\m\per\s}
\si{\metre\per\second}
```

where the behaviour of `\per` is selectable. For the 'literal' input

```
\si{m\per s}
```

parsing is not possible ('literal' input could be anything), and instead `\per` switches to simply inserting a `/`. Thus while the 'interpreted' mode requires slightly more typing, as it is more 'programmable' it's the recommended approach.